# Не могу поместить value в функцию

Tags: javascript, html

друзья! Проблема вот в чем.
Решил я написать примитивный калькулятор и все получилось, НО, в каждой функции математической операции лежит переменная которая достает value, которое вводит пользователь, если я объявляю переменную вне функции, в этом случаи функция не видит value.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать функцию которая это будет делать правильно.

```js
let out = document.getElementById('out');
let resultPlus = document.getElementById('resultPlus');
let result = document.getElementById('result');
let resultN = document.getElementById('resultN');
let resultP = document.getElementById('resultP');
let resultPr = document.getElementById('resultPr');
resultPlus.onclick = function() {
  let a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  let b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  out.innerHTML = (+a) + (+b);
};
result.onclick = function() {
  let a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  let b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  out.innerHTML = (+a) - (+b);
};
resultN.onclick = function() {
  let a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  let b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  out.innerHTML = (+a) * (+b);
};
resultP.onclick = function() {
  let a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  let b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  out.innerHTML = Math.floor(a / b);
};
resultPr.onclick = function() {
  let a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  let b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  out.innerHTML = a * (b / 100);
};
```

```html
<div class="calc">

<input type="number" id="a" placeholder = "Insert the number">

<input type="number" id="b" placeholder = "Insert the number">
<div class="buttons">
<button id="resultPlus">+</button>
<button id="result">-</button>
<button id="resultN">*</button>
<button id="resultP">/</button>
<button id="resultPr">%</button>
</div>
<p id="out">0</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let out = document.getElementById('out');
let resultPlus = document.getElementById('resultPlus');
let result = document.getElementById('result');
let resultN = document.getElementById('resultN');
let resultP = document.getElementById('resultP');
let resultPr = document.getElementById('resultPr');
let a, b;

function assignValues() {
  a = +document.getElementById('a').value;
  b = +document.getElementById('b').value;
}
resultPlus.addEventListener("click", assignValues);
result.addEventListener("click", assignValues);
resultN.addEventListener("click", assignValues);
resultP.addEventListener("click", assignValues);
resultPr.addEventListener("click", assignValues);

resultPlus.addEventListener("click", function() {
  out.innerHTML = a + b;
});
result.addEventListener("click", function() {
  out.innerHTML = a - b;
});
resultN.addEventListener("click", function() {
  out.innerHTML = a * b;
});
resultP.addEventListener("click", function() {
  out.innerHTML = Math.floor(a / b);
});
resultPr.addEventListener("click", function() {
  out.innerHTML = a * (b / 100);
});
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <input type="number" id="a" placeholder="Insert the number">
  <input type="number" id="b" placeholder="Insert the number">

  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="resultPlus">+</button>
    <button id="result">-</button>
    <button id="resultN">*</button>
    <button id="resultP">/</button>
    <button id="resultPr">%</button>
  </div>
  <p id="out">0</p>
</div>
```